# I need to set a function as eventlistener for an html element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener, dom-events

I have this html code

```
<div class = "select">

      <select class = "select-text">
        <option disabled selected> Select user </option>
      </select>

</div>

<button id = "oracle" class = "mdc-button"> Calculate BMI </button>
```

And this js code

```
const displaySelectedUser = () => {};     
const letsCalculateBMI = () => {};     
const powerupTheUI = () => {};
```

Using only DOM selector in the `powerupTheUI` function I am to

1. set `displaySelectedUser` as a change `eventlistener` for the div select class in the html
2. set `letsCalculateBMI` as a click event listener for the `#oracle` button

I've tried

```
document.querySelector(".select").addEventListener("change", displaySelectedUser());     
document.querySelector("#oracle").addEventListener("click", letsCalculateBMI());
```

And

```
let oracle = document.querySelector("#oracle");

oracle.addEventListener("click", () => {
    letsCalculateBMI();
});
```

But the test program won't accept it

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the function which be return the value return from function. Just don't call the function.

```
document.querySelector(".select").addEventListener("change", displaySelectedUser);
document.querySelector("#oracle").addEventListener("click", letsCalculateBMI);
```

**Note:** You will not be able to access the element clicked/changed by using `this` in a event handler if you are using Arrow Functions

Comment: OK. So what do I do then